# How to send request using urllib and continue with next commands without waiting for response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-multithreading

From my code I am trying to send request to a server and continue with other steps without waiting for response. This is because, sometimes the remote server is not sending response on time. But I do not want to block the code execution because of that. I am using urllib to send request.

Below is my code -

```
def myfunc(self):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(request_data).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request("http://serverurl:8046",data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
    print('Sent request, Continue execution') #this line should print immediately
    resp = 0
    return resp #the function call should return to the main calling function
```

Is it possible to achieve this ? Please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for "asynchronous requests". Look into the `asynаcio` and `aiohttp` modules.

Comment: You can also try the [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) module.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, the server I am working on is not having the requests and asynаcio modules. And there is no internet connection as well :( :( Any other way to achieve this ???

Comment: @ForceBru, can you please tell me what are the python modules needed to get this working, i will need to get those installed, as i understand i will need - 1. requests, 2. asynаcio, 3.aiohttp. Is there any other module required, I am having Python version 3.6. Also do you have any example code that I can refer to for the asynchronous communication ? Thanks.

Comment: @UPCH, you need `asyncio` (I typo’d in my previous comment) and `aiohttp`. The docs on both provide plenty of examples. BTW, if your server doesn’t have Internet access, there’s, as you understand, no way to to send requests anywhere except for other servers in your local network.

Comment: Yes, I am communicating between two servers within my network.

Comment: @blhsing, I am new to Python. Could you please show me an example how to do this using requests-futures module ? Thanks.